# Type mismatch error on VBA when using cell count as value

Tags: vba, excel

The following code will result in a

> Type Mismatch error

and will highlight the `Set Cnt = App...` line in yellow. I couldn't figure out what the problem is, I hope somebody can help me.

```
Dim Sel As Range

Set Sel = Selection

Sel.Offset(1, 2).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Dim Cnt As Variant
Set Cnt = Application.Selection.Cells.Count

Sel = Cnt.Value
```

Comment: `Count` returns a number, not an `Object` - So you don't use `Set`

Comment: .Count is a number, not an object. Maybe remove Set and just Sel = Cnt.

Comment: One line of code to do this `Selection = Range(Selection.Offset(1,2),Selection.Offset(1,2).End(xlDown)).Cells.Count` :) ... [avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers. @BraX: What should I use then?

Comment: @Jeeped If I just use Sel = Cnt and do not declare what Cnt is it won't work.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Thanks, I have tried to avoid it but wasn't really bothered because the whole thing wasn't working anyway :).

Comment: Eventually I won't want to use it as a value for a cell, but to declare how many times a loop has to repeat the action.